# django (djangorestframework-simplejwt) : How to set up SIGNING_KEY value different for each user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using djangorestframework-simplejwt  for setting up the jwt token based authentication

In my user model i have column

```
jwt_secret = models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

I wanted to use different jwt_secret for each token user.

So in future if i want to logoff a user from all places i can change this value

In can see djangorestframework-simplejwt  has a setting variable called `SIGNING_KEY`

How to mention in the settings that it should use per user based SIGNING_KEY

For more clearity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need to go that length to change secrets for each user. It will not only require changes within the library functions (overriding them in [backend](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/master/rest_framework_simplejwt/backends.py#L96), serializers, and views), it might potentially break in future. Rather you can look into [Blacklisting Apps](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_app.html) where you can block access tokens from the admin site. As described in the documentation:

> If the blacklist app is detected in INSTALLED_APPS, Simple JWT will add any generated refresh or sliding tokens to a list of outstanding tokens. It will also check that any refresh or sliding token does not appear in a blacklist of tokens before it considers it as valid. ... To add a token to the blacklist, find its corresponding OutstandingToken record in the admin and use the admin again to create a `BlacklistedToken` record that points to the `OutstandingToken` record.

Thus you can block a access token which essentially logging out an user from admin site. You can add further more functionality on top of `OutstandingToken` and `BlacklistedToken` models using signals to fulfil the use cases, or you can build a custom view to do that.